# create-react-app in WebStorm

Tags: node.js, npm, webstorm, create-react-app

I am attempting to use the npm package "create-react-app" to get started on a react project using WebStorm.

I have run `npm install -g create-react-app` to install the package globally, and can use the package perfectly fine with from the command line (i.e. `create-react-app <proj name>`).

However when creating a project in WebStorm and using the path to the global "create-react-app" package (found using `npm list -g`), I encounter this error:

```
/usr/bin/node /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/index.js .
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-app/createReactApp.js:589

    .filter(file => !validFiles.includes(file));
                            ^

TypeError: validFiles.includes is not a function
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-
app/createReactApp.js:589:33
    at Array.filter (native)
    at isSafeToCreateProjectIn (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-
react-app/createReactApp.js:589:6)
    at createApp (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-
app/createReactApp.js:147:8)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/create-react-
app/createReactApp.js:134:1)
    at Module._compile (module.js:410:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:417:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:344:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:301:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:354:17)
Done
```

Have I gone wrong at some point?

Comment: did you get a solution for this?

Comment: Yes, I resolved this by updating node to v6. Turns out create-react-app requires v6 or above, and this warning was not being output by the WebStrorm console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out I had node version 4, and create-react-app requires version >= 6 - although this warning was not displayed via the WebStorm "Run" panel.

Thus I fixed this issue by updating to node v6.11.3, using nvm.